# Fetching large dataset from firebase with android

Tags: android, web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am creating an fitness application in Android that is about storing different routes from google maps. These routes consist of lat and long coordinate points. I have managed to save these points, but I have problems in retrieving them. These routes can be quite big, so it could be several hundreds points per route.

I am now trying to fetch all the data from the firebase location and putting them in a list, and then using the list for displaying a polyline on a map. The problem is that the main thread is not waiting for the list to be filled with points so the list ends up with no points. The code I have now for fetching the points is like this:

```
        Firebase pointsRef = new Firebase(Config.POINTS_URL).child(point_collection_id);
        pointsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // do some stuff once
                Log.v("There are: ", snapshot.getChildrenCount() + "points");
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Point point = snap.getValue(Point.class);
                    Point otherPoint = new Point(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude());

                    Log.v("pointsLogging", "otherPoint.getLatitude()" +otherPoint.getLatitude());
                    Log.v("pointsLogging", "otherPoint.getLongitude()" + otherPoint.getLongitude());

                    listPoints.add(otherPoint);
                    Log.v("pointsLogging", "size of list in method" + listPoints.size());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    Log.v("pointsLogging", "listPoints.size()" + listPoints.size());
```

Here is the 
[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCgyy.jpg)

Is there anyway to check whether all the points has been added? Or does anyone know any better way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: Are you certain the program actually enters the for loop? If your Firebase reference is wrong, snapshot might be null.

Comment: Yes, when I log snapshot.getChildren() I get the correct amount of points, and when I log otherPoint.getLatitude() and otherPoint.getLongitude() it prints the coordinates.

Comment: When you say that the main thread is waiting for the results, how is it waiting? Infinite loop? Thread.sleep()? Just does nothing?

Comment: The problem is that is not waiting, look at the edited version of my question.